# What's the meaning of passing underscore _ "_" (_) when calling a function in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

When reading dart code I often see some functions called with just an underscore _ parameter. It's bugging me out for some time now and since flutter has improved its analysis messages I have some clues... but I feel like I don't really grasp this concept :-(

Yesterday I wrote the following for a test :

```
when(mockDevice.getLocalPath()).thenAnswer(() async => fileFolder);
```

and obtain the following analysis

> error: The argument type 'Future Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future Function(Invocation)'.

When adding underscore it's working perfectly.

```
when(mockDevice.getLocalPath()).thenAnswer((_) async => fileFolder);
```

The most frightenning example I meet come from provider package written by @remi rousselet

```
builder: (_, counter, __) => Translations(counter.value),
```

It's from the provider example :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => Counter()),
      ProxyProvider<Counter, Translations>(
        builder: (_, counter, __) => Translations(counter.value),
      ),
    ],
    child: Foo(),
  );
}

class Translations {
  const Translations(this._value);

  final int _value;

  String get title => 'You clicked $_value times';
}
```

Comment: First time I have down votes. Should I understand my question is seen as something to be discussed instead of answered ? I was looking for an answer and my strange title with many underscores is because it's hard to look for (_) on internet ;-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Underscore is normally an indication that you are not going to use that parameter inside the block it is just a good way to write code, for instance:

```
method(int useful, int useless) {
  // say I am only going to use 'useful' in this block 
}
```

Above code can also be written as:

```
method(int useful, int _) {
  // using '_' means I'm not going to use 2nd parameter in the block
}
```

---

Answer to your question now:

```
builder: (_, counter, __) => Translations(counter.value),
```

means you have 3 parameters `_`, `counter` and `__`, and only `counter` is what you are using, so 1st and 3rd parameters are denoted with `_` and `__`. This is just cleaner way to write code.

Comment: So, apart from teamwork purpose, I could write whatever I want instead of _ and using _ is just an unsaid convention ? Moreover we use it only for callback, non void callback since we use optional parameters in normal functions ?

Comment: Yes it's just unsaid convention, you can write whatever you want. And again yes, we generally use it for callbacks.

Comment: I see this as implementing some methods at Node. In some methods we pass the parameters req, res, next but we only use req or res (but you're required to implement the parameter even if you're not using it), for example. This is not a practice I see in JavaScript but I made the association now

Answer (score -3):

In Dart (the base language of flutter), if a class, class member, variable starts with an underscore, it means that it is private to its library. This is how dart typically deals with encapsulation as opposed to Java where you have your keywords like private, protected and public.

Comment: I think this is not the case of the question of the OP