# Using `Provider` in Firebase Auth does not work

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement Firebase Authentication in my Flutter app, with the help of `provider`. First, I am checking whether the user is already signed in. If yes, I am sending him to the **home** screen. Else I am sending him to the **Login** screen.

Please check my code below.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:customer/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ChangeNotifierProvider(
            child: MaterialApp(
                title: 'Customer App',
                
                home: AuthWrapper(), 
                routes: {
                    '/account': (context) => AccountPage(),
                },
            ), create: (BuildContext context) {
                AuthService();
            },
        );
    }
}
```

**auth.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthService with ChangeNotifier{

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser _user=null;

//Sign in with username and password
  Future signInWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
    FirebaseUser user;

    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
          user = result.user;

      if (user != null) {
        print("Sign in success: " + user.email);
        _user = user;
      } else {
        print("sign in failed");
        _user = null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    finally{
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

//Get the current user
  FirebaseUser getCurrentUser()  {
    return _user;
  }

}
```

**auth_wrapper.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:customer/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:customer/pages/login.dart';
import 'package:customer/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AuthWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  AuthWrapper() {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var currentUser =Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false).getCurrentUser();
    
    if (currentUser == null) {
      return LoginPage();
    } else {
      return HomePage();
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this app, i get the following error.

```
I/flutter ( 3364): The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building AuthWrapper(dirty):
I/flutter ( 3364): Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AuthService> above this AuthWrapper Widget
I/flutter ( 3364):
I/flutter ( 3364): To fix, please:
I/flutter ( 3364):
I/flutter ( 3364):   * Ensure the Provider<AuthService> is an ancestor to this AuthWrapper Widget
I/flutter ( 3364):   * Provide types to Provider<AuthService>
I/flutter ( 3364):   * Provide types to Consumer<AuthService>
I/flutter ( 3364):   * Provide types to Provider.of<AuthService>()
I/flutter ( 3364):   * Ensure the correct `context` is being used.
I/flutter ( 3364):
I/flutter ( 3364): If none of these solutions work, please file a bug at:
I/flutter ( 3364): https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues
I/flutter ( 3364):
I/flutter ( 3364): The relevant error-causing widget was:
[38;5;248mI/flutter ( 3364):   AuthWrapper[39;49m
I/flutter ( 3364):
I/flutter ( 3364): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
[38;5;248mI/flutter ( 3364): #0      Provider.of[39;49m
[38;5;248mI/flutter ( 3364): #1      AuthWrapper.build[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #2      StatelessElement.build[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #4      Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #5      ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #6      ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #7      Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #8      Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #9      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[3
```

I am newly trying out the `provider` patter, what's really going on here?

Comment: try this `create: (_) => AuthService(),` on the create

Comment: @TinusJackson: wow, this did work!!!! i have no idea! How is this supposed to work? Please submit your comment as an answer, with an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can do the following.

- Change the `create: (BuildContext context)` to `create: (_)`
  .You are not currently using the `BuildContext` thus it can be changed to `_` which is just cleaner code
- Secondly it does not seem that your function is returning the value to the create (I might be wrong on this). This is why the functional instantiation works better.

#### Examples from the provider package

```
 ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
```

#### Your code changes

So Change this

```
create: (BuildContext context) {
             AuthService();
},
```

To this

```
create: (_) => AuthService();
```

#### References

- [Using Underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58299530/4712391)
- [Provider Package - Examples taken from here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

If any one can explain the process of this better please assist.