# Why sometimes context is being replace as underscore or "_"?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

So recently I'm studying provider state management, and sometimes the instructor replacing context with a "_" or underscore.

For example when we are initializing the the changenotifierProvider:

```
 ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => ProductProvider(),
          ),
```

Another Example when we are trying to initialize a consumer:

```
Consumer<CartProvider>(
            builder: (_, cartProvider, child) {
              return Badge(
                child: child,
                value: cartProvider.itemCount
                    .toString(), 
              );
            },
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, CartScreen.routeName);
              },
            ),
          )
```

What kind of use cases that context is important in provider state management scenarios or others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this way used when you do not need to use this parameter, even it is the context or sometimes something else like the value.

see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58299530/13470875

Comment: But what kind of use cases, when context is being used in the consumer or provider?

Comment: there are some scenarios. This depends on the tree widget you want the provider to update. So if you have two tree widgets you can use 2 consumers with different contexts. or the most common case which almost all flutter programmers use is to wrap the MaterialApp inside the main method with the consumer and pass the context to update the full app widget when the authentication situation changes (this is very helpful if your app has Authentication).

Comment: Kindly, if I got you the idea, accept my answer by clicking on the right sign near the answer.