# Flutter Dart Syntax

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax

What is happening here?

`case '/front': return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FrontPage());`

What does the (_) mean? It should be a build context parameter value?

I have searched for Flutter, Dart explanation of the '(_)' usage but cannot find any.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299500/whats-the-meaning-of-passing-underscore-when-calling-a-function-in-da